# Test for change of proportion pattern

Tags: repeated-measures, proportion, multinomial-distribution

I am struggling with how to test for the change of a proportion pattern. The dependent variable $t$ is an amount of time which itself is partitioned into $n\geq3$ phases $t_i$. Thus, $t=\sum_{i=1}^n t_i$. There is a baseline and a post treatment measurement with treatment being a two level factor. The second measurement should not only be tested for a difference in the change of $t$ between the treatments but also for a change of the pattern of the proportions $p_i=t_i/t$. For instance consider the following crude example:

```r
> set.seed(103)
> trt = (((1:100)%%2) + 4)/3
> d = data.frame(trt = rep(0:1,50), t1 = exp(rnorm(100,3)), 
                 t2 = exp(rnorm(100,5)), t3 = exp(rnorm(100,2)), 
                 t1p = exp(rnorm(100,4))*trt, 
                 t2p = exp(rnorm(100,4))*trt, 
                 t3p = exp(rnorm(100,3))*trt)
> d[1:4, ]
  trt        t1        t2        t3       t1p       t2p      t3p
1   0  9.152498 368.56518  6.011215 163.57718 287.60124 37.29143
2   1 21.215645 359.93256  8.396521  23.19587  45.08169 59.35694
3   0  6.217946 102.17538  2.460465  63.27128  30.65995 31.13341
4   1 16.991058  32.20921 22.548838 224.24470 366.61612 72.90971
```

Let's first discard the effect of treatment. Then there is an overall positive effect of post baseline (at least I tried to model it but it doesn't seem to be reflected in the data). But what I am particularly interested in is the change of the proportions from $t_i/\sum t_i$ to $t_{ip}/\sum t_{ip}$. For each subject both of these sets of three variables obviously sum to 1. The baseline proportions (averaged over subjects via log and exp transformations, so they **don't** sum to 1) are $(0.08996525,0.73044067,0.03402201)$ post baseline they are $(0.3000452,0.3517296,0.1118583)$ which *looks* very different. But how do I test the hypothesis that they indeed are? Then, as I said I also want the interaction effect of post baseline by treatment, testing the question whether the treatment levels make the post baseline patterns differ. If $n$ was 2 it would be much easier, since then there is essentially only one variable because $t_2/\sum t_i=1-t_1/\sum t_i$. To clarify: I am not interested to test the change in just one $t_i$. I want an overall pattern change test.

Bonus question: What if I have more than one post baseline measurement. Is there a way to test the overall post basement effect of treatment with an MMRM?

**Edit:** Maybe I want too much so let me simplify. Is there a way to test for significant differences of the proportion pattern defined above either for two independent groups or for one group with two measures?